# Linked questions should take priority over some items in the sidebar

Tags: feature-request, linked-questions, sidebar

I just answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846770/t-sql-query-with-aggregates-returning-a-non-empty-result-set-when-predicate-is-f) where I linked a related question. I'm aware the link is in my answer, but I feel that if answers on a post link to other questions that might be useful to the OP or future visitors that they should be more prominent on the screen than some other items in the sidebar.

At present linked questions are in some cases, depending on what loads in your sidebar, below: Ads, Jobs and Chat.

[image]

Not sure if linked and related questions could be split, but I think it would be more useful to see linked questions further up, as it's potentially useful information, that might help people get to answers quicker... You never know, it *could even prevent a few low tier questions*.

If multiple answers link questions, then it would be even more useful to have them displayed more prominently. I'm not sure how often users link to other questions, but I'd say it's a smallish percentage, so it wouldn't impact that many posts or push ads too far down. Obviously there are [highly viewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server) questions that have lots of links, but these are in the minority of the overall questions on the site.

**The SO Tour**

Looking at the [SO Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the first few points seem to back this request:

[image]

Ads are important (to some), but it *could* be argued that they are a distraction as they don't help people get to answers, where as linked content from users *could.*

Comment: Even if the site-owners want those ads prominently displayed, it should at least take priority over the chat rooms!

Comment: Yeah, i get that ads and jobs help pay for things and I don't think this will impact a high percentage of posts heavily enough that it affects people seeing those items in the sidebar. This is aimed to get users to potential answers quicker by making those links more prominent. I didn't want to suggest the related links as those are just generated an algorithm somewhere, nobody has specifically added those as useful to the actual question.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163188/165773

Comment: @gnat That's over 4 years ago! Time to let it have some extra attention, in my opinion.

Comment: Adblock: 1, SO: 0

Comment: @gnat yeh that's related I guess, where this is posed as a FR rather than a q&a tagged as discussion. I searched MSO but couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: It should be above the Meta posts block as well. Linked questions are more relevant than Meta posts and that block doesn't change often.

Comment: Get an adblocker

Comment: Not sure I agree with that, @Dukeling. We want people to see featured activity on Meta; that's the whole point of the Community Bulletin. It announces new features (the correct way, not the "New!" badge way), solicits user feedback, and features burnination proposals---all things that people need to see, and evidence suggests that not nearly enough people are seeing currently. I'd rather have that at the top, for maximum visibility. People will scroll down for the "linked" questions. (Agreed that chat should go below it, though.)

Comment: @CodyGray I suppose the question is how important we consider linked posts. One might consider it on about the same level as comments, in which case: would we be happy doing the same to comments - reducing their visibility to feature Meta posts? Or one might consider it to be strictly summarising information, in which case I might say they should be hidden by default (e.g. click-to-expand). Although linked posts are somewhat inconsistent - sometimes they're duplicating very visible information, sometimes they're showing very relevant information not visible on the Q&A at all.

Comment: I've used an ad blocker before, but I chose not to for SO anymore, partially out of respect for the numerous times I've found useful content on the site that has helped me day to day, so I didn't feel it was right to deny a few ads being shown.